# How to restart a cycle that has been stopped?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Here's my case: http://jsfiddle.net/ehTE5/

I have two slideshows on the page, slide1 and slide2. When the page is loaded, slide1 automatically starts. What I want is when I click on the button "slide2" , slide1 will then stop and slide2 starts. Then when I click on the button "slide1" again while slide2 is running, I want slide2 to stop and slide1 to start all over again from the first slide like how it was when the page just loaded.

What I'm getting right now is, once I click on "slide2", no problem with slide1 stopping and slide2 starts. But when I click "slide1" button again while it's playing slide2, it goes back to slide1 but automatically stop the slideshow at the 2nd slide photo of slide2.

Anyone know what's going on?

I don't want to use the pause/resume function due to some restriction on the site I'm working on, besides I want to start all over from the very beginning not picking up where it left.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the documentation [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) you see you have the following options

```
'pause'   // pauses the slideshow, slideshow can be resumed with 'resume' command 
'resume'  // resumes a paused slideshow 
'toggle'  // toggles the pause/resume state of the slideshow 
'next'    // advances slideshow to next slide 
'prev'    // advances slideshow to previous slide 
'stop'    // stops the slideshow 
'destroy' // stops the slideshow and unbinds all events
```

so to stop you'll do `$("slider").cycle('pause')` and to start again you'll do `$("slider").cycle('resume')`

If you need to restart it, you probably need to `destroy` it and then reinitialize it

Comment: Thanks Manuel, once I destroy it, I couldn't reinitialize it. All the relative elements are destroyed as well. Do you know how to code it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HsYv3/  That's what happens when i use "destroy" instead. You can try click on "slide2" then "slide1" then click "slide2" again, it will automatically stop at the 2nd slide photo just like how it was when i used "stop" command.